# how to create jquery hover

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

How do I create a jQuery `hover` to show a `div` when the mouse is over like twitter repla retweet and favorite?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div style="display:none;" id="blab">
  <?php echo $blab_id; ?>
</div>
<a href="blab.php?id=<?php echo $blab_id; ?>">
    <div class="blab_body" id="hover" value="Hide">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <img src="<?php echo $profile_pic_info; ?>" class="blab_image" width="50" height="50" />
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <a href="profile.php?id=$mem_id">
                                    <strong><?php echo $added_fullname; ?></strong>
                                </a>
                                <?php echo $added_to_fullname; ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $blab_body; ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <text style="color:gray;">
                                    <?php echo $blab_date; ?>|<?php echo $device; ?>
                                </text>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div style="background:#000; display:none;" id="id">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</a>
<hr />
```

and here is my JavaScript code:

```
$('#id').hide();

$('#hover').hover(function () {
    var blab_id = $('#blab').text();
    $('#id').show();
}, function () {
    $('#id').hide();
});
```

It shows the `div` for the first one only.

Comment: Prepare code for better analyze, drop PHP code, leave only code to for question...

Comment: Please post the relevant **rendered** HTML not the PhP design code as it is not visible what HTML is rendered in it's place.

Answer (score 0):

**You can only use a certain ID once on the whole page!** If you insert more than one copy of this `div` on the page, your HTML code becomes invalid. That's why jQuery only attaches the event handler to the first element.

The solution is to use `class="hover_enabled"` instead of `id="hover"` as it is allowed to add the same class to multiple elements. Here is how you would do it in jQuery:

```
$('.hover_enabled').hover(function() { ...
```

The same thing applies to `#id`.